# $S^2$ expectation value of a circuit seems wrong

Tags: qiskit, cirq, angular-momentum

I need to rewrite a following circuit from [Cirq](https://quantumai.google/cirq) to [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/) with $2\varphi = \pi$.

[image]

It's a circuit representing an initial state for VQE calculation. Considering, that `qiskit_nature` considers a different ordering of spin-orbitals (first all spin-up, then all spin-down), I've rewritten the circuit like this (switching 1st and 2nd qubit, indexing from 0):

[image]

In both cases the statevector equals to

```
array([ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,
       -0.        ,  0.70710678, -0.        ,  0.        , -0.70710678,
        0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,
       -0.        ])
```

, i.e.

$$
\left|\psi\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 0110 \right> - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 1001 \right>.
$$

In Cirq, the total angular momentum $\left<\psi \middle| S^2 \middle| \psi \right> = 0$, i.e. the state should be singlet. But when I try the same in qiskit with the help of [second_q_ops()](https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.problems.second_quantization.ElectronicStructureProblem.second_q_ops.html), I'm getting `1.999999...`.

Why does my result differ?

---

#### My Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import qiskit_nature
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.providers.aer import Aer
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit_nature.converters.second_quantization import QubitConverter
from qiskit_nature.drivers import Molecule
from qiskit_nature.drivers.second_quantization import ElectronicStructureMoleculeDriver, ElectronicStructureDriverType
from qiskit_nature.mappers.second_quantization import JordanWignerMapper
from qiskit_nature.problems.second_quantization import ElectronicStructureProblem
from qiskit_nature.transformers.second_quantization.electronic import ActiveSpaceTransformer

if __name__ == '__main__':

    qiskit_nature.settings.dict_aux_operators = True
    backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

    geometry = [('N', [0.000000000000, 0.000000000000, 0.000000000000]),
                ('C', [0.000000000000, 0.000000000000, 1.498047000000]),
                ('H', [0.000000000000, -0.938765985000, 2.004775984000]),
                ('H', [0.000000000000, 0.938765985000, 2.004775984000]),
                ('H', [-0.744681452, -0.131307432, -0.634501434])]

    # Obtaining ground state
    driver = ElectronicStructureMoleculeDriver(Molecule(geometry),
                                               basis="sto3g",
                                               driver_type=ElectronicStructureDriverType.PSI4)

    as_transformer = ActiveSpaceTransformer(num_electrons=2, num_molecular_orbitals=2)
    es_problem = ElectronicStructureProblem(driver, transformers=[as_transformer])
    converter = QubitConverter(JordanWignerMapper())

    # Create circuit
    qreg_q = QuantumRegister(4, 'q')
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q)

    circuit.x(qreg_q[2])
    circuit.ry(np.pi, qreg_q[0])
    circuit.ch(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[3])
    circuit.cx(qreg_q[3], qreg_q[2])
    circuit.cx(qreg_q[3], qreg_q[0])
    circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1])
    circuit.z(qreg_q[3])
    circuit.x(qreg_q[0])
    print(f'Circuit:\n{circuit}')

    statevec = Statevector(circuit).data
    print(f'Statevector:\n{statevec}')

    # Obtain S^2 operator
    ss_op = es_problem.second_q_ops()['AngularMomentum']
    print(f'S^2 operator:\n{ss_op}')

    print(f'<psi|S^2|psi> = {statevec @ converter.convert(ss_op).to_matrix() @ statevec}')
```

#### The Output

```
Circuit:
     ┌───────┐          ┌───┐     ┌───┐
q_0: ┤ Ry(π) ├──■───────┤ X ├──■──┤ X ├
     └───────┘  │       └─┬─┘┌─┴─┐└───┘
q_1: ───────────┼─────────┼──┤ X ├─────
       ┌───┐    │  ┌───┐  │  └───┘     
q_2: ──┤ X ├────┼──┤ X ├──┼────────────
       └───┘  ┌─┴─┐└─┬─┘  │  ┌───┐     
q_3: ─────────┤ H ├──■────■──┤ Z ├─────
              └───┘          └───┘     
Statevector:
[ 0.00000000e+00+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j
  0.00000000e+00+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j  6.12323400e-17+0.j
  7.07106781e-01+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j
 -7.07106781e-01+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j
  0.00000000e+00+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j
  0.00000000e+00+0.j]
S^2 operator:
Fermionic Operator
register length=4, number terms=12
  (0.75+0j) * ( +_0 -_0 )
+ (0.75+0j) * ( +_1 -_1 )
+ (0.75+0j) * ( +_2 -_2 )
+ (0.75+0j) * ( +_3 -_3 )
+ (0.5+0j) * ( +_0 -_0 +_1 -_1 )
+ (-1.5+0j) * ( +_0 -_0 +_2 -_2 )
+ (-0.5+0j) * ( +_0 -_0 + ...
<psi|S^2|psi> = (1.9999999999999996+0j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are the same person who raised [this issue](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/issues/816). Let me re-direct anyone to my [reply on Github](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/issues/816#issuecomment-1236767761) instead of duplicating it here.