# How to rewrite the quantum state to qubits?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state

I have a following state (indexing everything from 0 here)

$$
| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( | \uparrow_0 \downarrow_1 \rangle - | \downarrow_0 \uparrow_1 \rangle \right)
$$

and I need to be able to rewrite it in Qiskit notation in a computational basis.

I know, that Qiskit orders the spin-orbitals with all spin-up first and spin-down afterwards, e.g. when we have 2 molecular orbitals, it looks like

- [0]: $\uparrow$ MO0
- [1]: $\uparrow$ MO1
- [2]: $\downarrow$ MO0
- [3]: $\downarrow$ MO1

with qubit position given by an index in square brackets.

So, how can I approach the conversion to qubits? My idea is, that I can rewrite it in a way, where $| 0 \rangle$ will be an unoccupied spin-orbital and $|1\rangle$ an occupied orbital, i.e. the one present in $|\psi\rangle$ expression.

Thus, I'd approach it like this:
$$| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |1001\rangle - |0110\rangle \right)$$

Is it the correct approach (and result :)?

Comment: So, you have two degrees of freedom, up-down and zero-one in the first equation?

Comment: @R.W Yes, 2 spins and 2 molecular orbitals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct. You have implicitly made use of the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation) to map the spin-1/2 fermions to qubits. Incidentally, there is a recent related post ([$S^2$ expectation value of a circuit seems wrong](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28049/s2-expectation-value-of-a-circuit-seems-wrong)) that provides a circuit to prepare this fermionic valence-bond state.